# I am trying to print date in scala but its not printing proper value

Tags: scala

My code. Just mentioned date part.

```
case class data (id:String, date:String, temp:Int, pressure:Int, humidity:Int)

val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

val date1=date.toString

var first= new data(id1,date1,temp,press,hum)
```

My output is

```
date":"java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1a0"
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is a formatter. It doesn't contain a date, it is used to format or parse a date. For instance: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2018-02-20"))` which produces `2018-02-20 00:00:00`

Comment: Your date is just an instance of a `SimpleDateFormat` - what is the actual date? Doing `.toString` doesn't give you a date. You need to parse an actual date to get a `Date` instance, then you can put that into your case class. Even better is to make your `date` in the case class a `Date` type.

Comment: Unless you have any good reasons not to use `java.time`, please [don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/) it's an obsolete and terrible api.

Comment: And please explain your concept of "Date", it's not at all obvious from your code what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `SimpleDateFormat` is a formatter for a `Date`.

You first need a `java.util.Date` and then you can have the string representation with the formatter

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

val d = new Date()
val dateString = sdf.format(d)

println(dateString)

//output: 2018-02-20 10:00:00
```

Comment: [Don't use java.util.Date](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Comment: I agree, it's only related to explain the `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Date` API a bit dated, and I would strongly discourage you from using it. Use the (much more sane) `java.time` instead.

In case that you decide to switch to `java.time`, see the answer below.

---

The `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` in your code merely instantiates a formatter. It does not produce any date that it could 
format. The string "java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1a0" is not a properly formatted date, it is merely the output of the standard `toString` method of the formatter. In order to get the string representation of a formatted date, you have to:

- instantiate a formatter
- instantiate a date
- pass the date to the formatter

With `java.time`, this would look somehow like this:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._

val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val currentDateInUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
val date1: String = formatter format currentDateInUTC

println(date1)
```

Prints:

```
2018-02-20 17:57:28
```